# Проблема с позиционированием элементов

Tags: html, css

```css
.section1{
 height:843px;
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 50px;
 position: relative;
 
}
.imgcenter{
 display: block;
 margin: auto;

}
.deskr{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);

}
```

```html
<div class="section1">
  <img src="img/10.png" alt="Alt" class=imgcenter >
  <span class="deskr">
   Какой-то текст
  </span>
 
 </div>
```

Мне нужно чтобы текст был поверх картинки и затемнение там же.[image: Как показано на картинке. Пожалуйста, помогите спать не могу]

Comment: могли бы Вы продублировать Ваш пример на https://codepen.io ?

Comment: просто для `.deskr` добавьте `z-index="1"`

Answer (score 0):

Чуть-чуть подправил название классов:

```css
.img-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}
.img-block__item {
 padding: 5px;
}
.img-block__content {
  position: relative;
}
.img-block__text {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-block">
  <div class="img-block__item">
    <div class="img-block__content">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Alt" class=img-block__img >
      <span class="img-block__text">
        Какой-то текст
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="img-block__item">
    <div class="img-block__content">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Alt" class=img-block__img >
      <span class="img-block__text">
        Какой-то текст
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="img-block__item">
    <div class="img-block__content">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Alt" class=img-block__img >
      <span class="img-block__text">
        Какой-то текст
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @ЯрославПрокофьев выделите пожалуйста, как верный ответ, спасибо